# delimiting a column based on the number of delimiters within that column

Tags: r, delimiter, strsplit

I have a vector list.exp2 where each entry is one or more strings separated by commas. I would like to split each entry and take the first n number of strings based on the number of delimiters present in that entry.

I've tried the below code but am not successful yet

```
refined.final.list <- as.vector(sapply(list.exp2, function(n)
         ifelse(count.fields(textConnection(list.exp2[n]), sep = ",") < 3,
                unlist(strsplit(list.exp2[n], ","))[1],
                count.fields(textConnection(list.exp2[n]), sep = ",") < 5, 
                unlist(strsplit(list.exp2[n], ","))[1:2],
                unlist(strsplit(list.exp2[n], ","))[1:4])))
```

Basically, I used the ifelse along with the count function that gives me a count of the number of delimiters and the unlist function is suppose to give me corresponding split elements.

The list.exp2 vector looks like this

```
lis.exp2 <- c("ISTITUTO PER LA SINTESI ORGANICA E LA FOTOREATTIVITÀ (ISOF-CNR), 
               SEZIONE DI FERRARA, VIA L. BORSARI 46, 44100 FERRARA, ITALY",
              "FLUXOME SCIENCES A/S, SØLTOFTS PLADS, BUILDING 223, DK-2800 KGS. LYNGBY, DENMARK",
              "FERDINAND-BRAUN-INSTITUT FÜR HÖCHSTFREQUENZTECHNIK, GUSTAV-KIRCHHOFF-STR. 4, 12489 BERLIN, GERMANY")
```

Any insights into how to correct this code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ifelse(test, truevalue, falsevalue)` should only have three arguments, not five. You need to nest them if you have several conditions - e.g. `ifelse(test, truevalue, ifelse(test2, truevalue2, falsevalue))`

Comment: I actually am doing the same thing. It only appears like five arguments. I have another set of code that has better ifelse appearing structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use `strsplit` directly on your vector `lis.exp2`. It will result into a list with one item for each item from vector. Then use `lapply` to return desired number of element.

Example to return 3 items as:

```
n <- 3
lapply(strsplit(lis.exp2, split=","), function(x)x[1:n])

#OR Based on @thelatemail suggestion

lapply(strsplit(lis.exp2, split=","), head, n)

#Result
# [[1]]
# [1] "ISTITUTO PER LA SINTESI ORGANICA E LA FOTOREATTIVITÀ (ISOF-CNR)"
# [2] " SEZIONE DI FERRARA"                                            
# [3] " VIA L. BORSARI 46"                                             
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "FLUXOME SCIENCES A/S" " SØLTOFTS PLADS"      " BUILDING 223"       
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "FERDINAND-BRAUN-INSTITUT FÜR HÖCHSTFREQUENZTECHNIK"
# [2] " GUSTAV-KIRCHHOFF-STR. 4"                          
# [3] " 12489 BERLIN"
```

**UPDATED:**Based on feedback from OP
A function can be written which check if number of items less than (`say 4`) then return only 1st items else return top 3 items.

```
#Function to return top 1/3 items based on condition
getNItems <- function(x){
  if(length(x) <= 4){
    #only 1st
    x[1]
  }else{
    #first 3
    x[1:3]
  }
}                                 
lapply(strsplit(lis.exp2, split=","), getNItems)
```

Comment: You could also use `lapply(strsplit(lis.exp2, split=","), head, n)` which might be a bit less esoteric.

Comment: This code seems useful. However, I want varying n values (or head) depending on the number of strings in that element.  

Hence my challenge/problem is to include this code in a function, that goes through each element of a vector, and if the number of strings in that element is few then I want only the 1st string of that element. Consequently, if there are many, then the I want the first three strings of that element.

Comment: @JGG Modified answer. Hopefully that will resolve your problem.

Comment: It did. Thank you.

Comment: @JGG Glad to know that it worked for your. You can accept the answer by clicking on `tick` mark in left my answer. That will be helpful to future users.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the request, you already have separate items in a character vector and want to parse the interiors of these elements into as many sub-items as are separated by comma. The scan function does hat neatly:

```
sapply(lis.exp2, function(x) {scan( text=x,what="", sep=",")})
Read 5 items
Read 5 items
Read 4 items
$`ISTITUTO PER LA SINTESI ORGANICA E LA FOTOREATTIVITÀ (ISOF-CNR), SEZIONE DI FERRARA, VIA L. BORSARI 46, 44100 FERRARA, ITALY`
[1] "ISTITUTO PER LA SINTESI ORGANICA E LA FOTOREATTIVITÀ (ISOF-CNR)"
[2] " SEZIONE DI FERRARA"                                            
[3] " VIA L. BORSARI 46"                                             
[4] " 44100 FERRARA"                                                 
[5] " ITALY"                                                         

$`FLUXOME SCIENCES A/S, SØLTOFTS PLADS, BUILDING 223, DK-2800 KGS. LYNGBY, DENMARK`
[1] "FLUXOME SCIENCES A/S" " SØLTOFTS PLADS"      " BUILDING 223"       
[4] " DK-2800 KGS. LYNGBY" " DENMARK"            

$`FERDINAND-BRAUN-INSTITUT FÜR HÖCHSTFREQUENZTECHNIK, GUSTAV-KIRCHHOFF-STR. 4, 12489 BERLIN, GERMANY`
[1] "FERDINAND-BRAUN-INSTITUT FÜR HÖCHSTFREQUENZTECHNIK"
[2] " GUSTAV-KIRCHHOFF-STR. 4"                          
[3] " 12489 BERLIN"                                     
[4] " GERMANY"
```